# Trying to understand recursion through a list of integers

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, negation

I am currently learning how to use recursion in Haskell and I am trying to understand how to go through every element in a list of integers and negate them. So far I can do this but only on the final element of the list so I know that the error lies in the last line. What is the best way to go through every element in a list rather than just the final one?

```
negation :: [Int] -> [Int]
negation [] = []
negation [n] = [-n]
negation(x:xs) = negation xs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `cons` operator `:` to put the negated number at the front of the list.

```
negation (x:xs) = -x : negation xs
```

If you do that, you can get rid of the third line.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks very much for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the best way to write your function is this:

```
negation :: [Int] -> [Int]
negation xs = map negate xs

{- Example:

>>> map negate [1..5]
[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]
-}
```

**Exercise:** write your own version of `map`:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap _ [] = _fillMeIn
myMap f (x:xs) = _fillMeIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple with map:

```
  Prelude> let negatList= map (*(-1))
```

Examples:

```
  Prelude> negatList []
  []
  Prelude> negatList [1]
  [-1]
```

With recursion:

```
 negation :: [Int] -> [Int]
 negation [] = []
 negation(x:xs) = -x:negation xs
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in an answer before, the best way is to use higher order functions as follows

```
negation xs = map negate xs
```

Always use higher order functions whenever possible. It is one of the general Haskell programming guidelines present on wiki.haskell.org and it simplifies your code.